# Doctrine error during migrations

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created entities on my Symfony project, but when I execute migrations, I received this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

I've created these two entities 'Post' and 'Tag' with ManyToMany associations:

App\Entity\Post

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_tag",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_code", referencedColumnName="code")}
 *      )
 */
private $tags;
```

App\Entity\Tag:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", mappedBy="tags")
 */
private $posts;
```

The migrations should create the pivot table 'post_tag' with post_id and tag_code as primary keys. How can I fix the error?

Comment: Is your charset for doctrine in config.yml set to UTF8? `doctrine: dbal: charset: UTF8`

Comment: @J.Hpour no, it sets to: utf8mb4

Comment: Can you change it to utf8 and try to execute migration again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved the problem changed the length of key from my 'post_tag' table

Answer (score 0):

let you try adding the following code in to boot() method of AppServiceProvider.php:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Comment: In Symfony theresn't this file, where I can found it?

Comment: this file is in  'app/Providers/AppServiceProvider'

Answer (score 0):

Add to `AppServiceProviders.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```